# Update a Struts tiles with Ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, struts2, tiles

i have a question for you with no code :)
I have a Struts2 Web Application composed by several tiles. The main tile called content, show the interface for the business use case currently in use.
In one case, I have a content tile composed by only some Jquery accordion and one button "Add". On the action linked to the tiles, I have a collection of oblects. When the tile is open by the user, i loop trouhg the collection to create on accordion 8the relation is 1 to 1).
The Add button add an entry into my collection. After the add, I am aspecting to see another accordion on the page.
Is there a way to refresh the tiles withpout he entire page??

Answer (score 0):

Yes one way is have an action return json, the struts2-json-plugin makes this very easy.

See: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/JSON%20Plugin

Handling the json on the client side then becomes a JS/JS library question.